# DataGrip sort more rows than page size

Tags: sql, sorting, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

In JetBrains DataGrip, when I try to sort a column (descending for example), it only shows and sorts loaded rows - that means 500 (it's the set page size). Is it possible that it can sort all rows (in my table like 25 000)?

I don't want to manually type `order by column_name desc` everytime I want to sort something.

In DBeaver this kind of sorting works.

Comment: What is the version of DataGrip? IN the latest version ORDER BY is executed once sorting action is invoked. See https://i.imgur.com/lZttgXu.png

Comment: Thank you, I thought it works the same as DBeaver, so I had "select * from table" and then in services window I was trying to sort it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn *Sort via ORDER BY* option on. So it will concat the `ORDER BY` for you.

[image]

Alternatively, you can always fetch all rows (use the corresponding setting) and client-based sorting will also sort all rows :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I have to manually search for the database in Database Explorer. I just did "select" query and then trying to sort it in services window.